# About resonant capacitor

Tags: resonance, mlcc

I have selected all my components except for the resonant capacitor. 1uF C0G MLCC is hard to find where I live. I checked almost every component distributor website but no results. I want to know how different it would be if I use X5R and X7R instead of C0G. Or is there any material that is close to C0G to get a similar performance?

Comment: Performance is a definition of the circuit it is used in; the voltages, the currents, the frequencies and, the acceptable drift in capacitance with temperature. What do you need? What is your circuit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the usual component vendors are also present in Turkey...? And well, one doesn't specify 1uF C0G unless there's some very peculiar specialized requirements. Most caps that "big" are decoupling/bulk caps without much in the way of accuracy concerns.

Comment: Film capacitors may be a better choice.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473002/are-1uf-np0-c0g-capacitors-different-than-regular-1uf-capacitors

Answer (score 0):

COG 1uF indeed is hard to find anywhere. The only one I see in stock at Digikey costs $90 USD and is 10mm x 10mm.

You can parallel 10 pieces of 25 cent 100nF COG/NP0 capacitors however.

X5R and X7R are cheap and small for the capacitance but have relatively big temperature coefficients and often very large voltage coefficients, so they are poor choices where the capacitance value should remain fairly constant. If you have a non-critical circuit with very little voltage across it (say hundreds of mV)  in a constant temperature environment maybe it will work for you, we can't really guess your application requirements, of course.

Comment: If you *need* C0G style performance in a 1 μF capacitor, a film capacitor is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Lundin X7S in the description; incorrectly cataloged, suggest reporting it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yuck indeed... I just noticed and reported. I should know better than to trust the brain-dead component searches of Digikey and Mouser et al to ever be correct...

Comment: I mean, they're certainly right more often than they're wrong. Just a matter of keeping a critical eye out; as in all things!

Comment: @Hearth NP0 ceramic capacitors are typically 5-10x better in terms of temperature coefficient than common film caps. You'd have to compare DA and other characteristics too.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, but film is closer to C0G/NP0 than X7R is, was my point. And the voltage coefficient is similarly small, which is the main reason I typically worry about capacitor dielectric material--though I suppose my personal use case isn't necessarily representative. (I mostly work on test equipment and only occasionally need to worry about temperature when designing boards that will go into ovens or be used with temperature forcing systems.)